# How can I capture (high definition) audio and video from my Xbox 360 and PS3?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, recording

How do I set up my Xbox 360, PS3, and TV so that I can record high-definition videos of gameplay?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a zillion ways, but here's a good walkthrough of one way:

http://goodblimey.com/archives/2008/02/06/how-to-record-xbox-360-gameplay-videos/

Apparently this approach requires the following

- [HAVA Platinum HD](http://myhava.com/product_hava_platinum_hd.html) placeshifter device ($120)
- Two (2) triple phono couplers ($2.94 plus $2 shipping [at Monoprice.com](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10401&cs_id=1040107&p_id=3002&seq=1&format=2))
- Xbox 360 console with component cord

Answer (score 0):

[Pinnacle](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Products/Consumer+Products/Dazzle/Dazzle+Video+Archiving/Dazzle+Video+Creator+Plus+HD.htm) is the first thing that popped up. It says HD, but I don't see anything in the instruction manual about HDMI inputs. Looks like composite and S-Video inputs only...

Answer (score 0):

You could always run your console through a Tivo HD (which is only about 200) and will serve other purposes (such as Tivo)